# A qustion for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter deprecated

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In new Spring Security, what should I do to replace these code follw:

```java
@Override protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder).and().eraseCredentials(false); }
```

I hope to get the lasted code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

For spring boot version 3 you can refer my code :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;


    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    private final JwtFilter filter;

    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint point;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests().
                requestMatchers("/category/add")
                .authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/authenticate","/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(point))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new CustomAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

CustomAuthentcationManager :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return authenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, spring boot version is 2.7.0. tow questions: 1. login failed for username or password error, but when I test, by using method loadUserByUsername() and using method passwordEncoder.matches("123456", userDetails.getPassword())success;2. lack CustomAuthenticationManager class

Comment: @gold-three   I have updated the code with CustomAuthenticationManager class.